# Расположение в верхней части

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать приложение с 2-мя activity.
Расположение на них элементов следующее: 
[image]

Как лучше это сделать?  Оставить сверху actionBar или сделать layout дополнительный?
Я не знаю как, например, сделать так, чтобы название приложения в actionBar было по середине,как скрывать/показывать кнопку "reload", как сделать так, чтобы стрелка "home" отображалась, а текста был по середине.

**UPD**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reload_button);
    menuItem.setEnabled(true);
    menuItem.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

С ActionBar конечно. Кнопку меню скрыть можно, например, вызвав setHasOptionsMenu(false), либо другое макет для меню подгрузив. Также, для action bar можно установить свой custom-макет, который будет выглядеть как угодно, но правда на счет центрирования текста не знаю, нужно проверять опытным путем, но проблем с Action Bar как правило нет. Просто, в итоге получится меньше кода чем ручками писать все тоже самое.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда вопросы: Как скрывать/показывать кнопку "reload"? Как изменить цвет фона actionBar?

Comment: Я же написал. Вы делаете полностью свой макет для бара - инфлейтите его и юзаете как угодно. И кнопку скрывать в чем проблема то? Все зависит от контекста же.

Comment: А как написать свой макет для бара? Просто никогда этого не делал...  
Кнопку скрыть/показать не получается - добавил код

Comment: Как обычный макет любой. Потом через LayoutInflater его получаете и вызываете actionBar.setCustomView(view). Кнопку скрыть можно как я уже написал через setHasOptionsMenu(false), но думаю можно и иначе.

Comment: Да я просто никогда этого не делал. Можно где-то пример посмотреть?

Comment: Например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar  или http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#menu_customviews ну и в гугле по запросу android action bar custom view

Comment: Благодарю. Уже гуглил вчера на эту тему: так вот, некоторые при кастомизации еще зачем-то добавляют свой стиль для активити: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android     
Зачем? И потом, можно ли сделать кастомную вьюшку для бара явно не указывая в ней кнопку "back", а потом прописать actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);?

Comment: Зачем тогда прописывать setDisplayHome() если у вас она своя будет? это не к чему. Она по факту просто finish() делает в активити, ну возможно что-то еще или вызывает onBackPressed(), смотря какая логика вообщем. Тема это просто набор свойств стилей. В данном случае они меняют минимальную ширину.